# Schema changes to an active MongoDB Realm Sync

Tags: mongodb, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration, mongodb-realm

I'm new to MongoDB Realm and hence experimenting with it. From what I've seen is that I can't modify the Realm Schema (except for when in Development mode!) from the Realm UI without terminating and restarting the Realm Sync process.

My concern is that what is the ideal way to perform a production deployment when a Realm Sync Schema needs to be changed (or say a new collection is added!)?

I was going through the docs on [Terminating & Re-enabling Sync](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/reference/terminating-and-reenabling-realm-sync/), and nowhere does it mention that you need to restart sync when deploying new changes; hence I'm assuming that there is some information / best practice that I'm missing.

Comment: The question is a bit vague. If you're modifying the schema, that means you're also adding code to support those changes; that would be done in development mode before you roll out a new version of your production app, right? When you say modifications *from the Realm UI*, what does *Realm UI* mean in this case; the Realm console? Also *a new collection* would indicate you've added a new Ream App to the console; is that what you mean? A Realm App (Console->Realm tab) is backed by a database (a collection). Are you asking about using two collections with one app? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay My question was more concerned with performing a client reset whenever the Atlas collection structure & Realm Schema / Object Model is changed. As per this link -- https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/dotnet/client-reset/ -- we do need to perform a client reset whenever there is a destructive change in schema. I was looking for some reference to confirm that what I was thinking was indeed true and not a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: @Jay I'd like to hear your thoughts on what are the best practices when doing a production deployment for Realm? Say I've an app already in production and I make some schema changes to fit a new requirement (using the development mode and iterating through schema changes); and then performing a client reset during production deployment (which might cause data loss - https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/dotnet/client-reset/). How do you prevent data loss in such a situation?

Comment: When you say data loss, what do you mean? Remember Realm is a offline first database; local data is well, local data, and you can delete everything on the server and that won't delete the data on the device - just like if you wipe the clients device it won't delete the data on server. We probably need a clearer explanation of the use case where there would be data loss. Can you update the question with more info?

Comment: @Jay What I mean is summarized in the warning on the link from my prior comment. It states that  -- "A client reset erases all local data and downloads a new copy of the data stored in MongoDB Atlas. Performing a client reset loses all local changes made since the client last successfully synced."  I tried this myself today, I created 3 synced collections in Atlas and 3 objects on the client side. I deleted one collection schema on Atlas end, and then the sync threw an error 208 “Bad server file identifier (IDENT)”. I had to perform a client reset using `Realm.deleteFiles(for: config)` to fix.

Comment: So if we have to perform a client reset in case of schema changes, then the pending changes from the client db can be lost.

Comment: I see, I was assuming that all the data had been sync'd when you were doing a reset. When you do a 'client reset' it's actually more like a 'server reset' which then tells the client via a message that a reset it required which can be handled in code. I think there's an example of handling that situation to allow a user to elegantly exit the app and restart to receive updated data.

Comment: @Jay I just came across one example with a help of a gentleman from the MongoDB forums. I'm trying that right now with all the doubts that I have, and as per my new understanding what you're saying about "server reset" kind of makes sense. I'll let you know how it goes and once again thank you for solving all my doubts related to MDB :)